# Automapper and conditional mapping with Record types

Tags: automapper, record

to use conditional mapping with automapper , I normally go for  a code like this

> .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedDate, opt =>
> {
> opt.PreCondition(src => src.UpdatedBy != null);
> opt.MapFrom(src => src.UpdatedDate);
> })

now , for  automapper with record types in c#10 , we need to use ForCtorParam instead of ForMember , as soon as you use ForCtorParam , have not access to precondition and other features like Resolvers anymore .
how can we manage this and using automapper for records as simple as using for the classes specially for DTO ones . seems that ForCtorParam is working fine but only for a simple scenarios . any idea what to do ?

many thanks

Comment: Drop the `PreCondition` and put your code inside the `MapFrom`. Or have mutable records and keep your existing code.

Comment: If fact AM will work with private setters, so, if you disable constructor mapping, you can still use immutable records.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu : thanks lucian , do you mean something like this  (from AM documents)  :                                                                                                                    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.DisableConstructorMapping());                                                                                     i used this type of configuration but still using MapFrom for immutable types is not possible and ended with error " needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args"

Comment: Well, yes, you do need such a constructor. There is no other way it could possibly work.

Comment: I finally used positional record types ( {get ; init ;} ) . seems this is the only way for the meanwhile . many thanks